# Azure ad sdk doesnot fetch Intunes company portal login for SSO

Tags: ios, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory, azure-sdk, authenticator

I have integrated Azure ad in my iOS app. I need to perform SSO when I have already logged into my Comp Portal app(Microsoft Intunes).

Note: I am able to perform auto sign-in when I have Authenticator app installed, however this doesn't work if I have only Comp Portal App installed.

On android its working fine, but no luck over iOS.

Comment: @DanielDobalian could you plz share your input on this?

Comment: Have you added the keychain groups for Adal and Intunes in your capabilities.

Comment: yes I did. What I found here is the macro that we pass as login type= automatic. this constant prefers best user login experience and only tries to locate Another app having ADAL lib or authenticator(broker) app. It does not sense presence of Comp Portal app!